# Is there any way to build a JSON that looks like this using SQL Server 2019?

Tags: json, sql-server, for-json

I have this SQL Query:

```sql
SELECT
    c.customer_name as name,
    c.customer_ssn as social_number,
    c.telephone as telephone,
    c.email as email,
    u.user_name as name
FROM
    Customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    User u ON c.id_customer = u.id_customer
WHERE 
    c.id_customer = 2
FOR JSON PATH

SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE ID_CUSTOMER = 2
SELECT * FROM User WHERE ID_Customer = 2
```

This query returns this JSON :

```json
[
    { 
      "name": "blablabla",
      "social": "123123123",
      "telephone": "91123123",
      "email": "blabla@gmail.com",
      "name":"blabla"
    }
]
```

Is there any way to get a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "blabla",
  "social_number": "123123123",
  "emails": [
    {
      "email": "blabla@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "email": "blablabla@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "telephones": [
    {
      "number": "(604)6622141"
    },
    {
      "number": "(652) 2123223"
    }
  ],
```

Thank you for the help!

I'm still new to coding and StackOverflow... sorry for any mistakes!

Comment: Didn't notice till after I'd added the code fences that you have html break lines in your code? I hope that aren't *actually* in your SQL. On a mobile that will be a pain to remove. Please take moment to format your question appropriately.

Comment: Done, the <br> aren't in my sql code!

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subqueries, with `FOR JSON` in each one

```sql
SELECT
    c.customer_name as name,
    c.customer_ssn as social_number,
    telephones = (
        SELECT telephone
        FROM telephone t
        WHERE t.id_customer = c.id_customer
        FOR JSON PATH
    ),
    emails = (
        SELECT email
        FROM email e
        WHERE e.id_customer = c.id_customer
        FOR JSON PATH
    ),
    u.user_name as name
FROM
    Customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    User u ON c.id_customer = u.id_customer
WHERE 
    c.id_customer = 2
FOR JSON PATH;
```

You can also do this as an `APPLY`

```sql
SELECT
    c.customer_name as name,
    c.customer_ssn as social_number,
    t.telephones,
    e.emails,
    u.user_name as name
FROM
    Customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    User u ON c.id_customer = u.id_customer
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT telephone
        FROM telephone t
        WHERE t.id_customer = c.id_customer
        FOR JSON PATH
) t(telephones)
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT email
        FROM email e
        WHERE e.id_customer = c.id_customer
        FOR JSON PATH
) e(emails)
WHERE 
    c.id_customer = 2
FOR JSON PATH;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
It worked perfectly!
Thank you!